# In Windows 10, where is a mounted folder's contents actually stored?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, file-management

Question 1)

Let's say I have a mounted folder to my D: drive in C:\Users\Me\Documents\Homework.

Let's say I save a file in there called Assignment1.txt.

Is the file location of Assignment1.txt actually D:?

Question 2)

Is creating a mounted folder the same as "mounting a hard drive as a volume in another drive?"

Comment: Do you know the difference between "physical disk", "partition", and "filesystem" ?

Comment: It is on D drive.

Comment: @BenVoigt From what I understand, a physical disk is a physical disk that is mounted by the OS and partitions are segments of the drive that are separated. NTFS is a filesystem.

Comment: @MeesterMoo: NTFS is a filesystem layout.  When you store data conforming to that layout into a partition, then you have a filesystem.  The default is that each filesystem instance gets its own drive letter.  Windows 10 is capable of several different "reparse point" aka "junction" types, including: Mounting a filesystem on one volume as a subdirectory of a different filesystem, mounting a subtree of a filesystem as a separate drive letter (aka `subst` command), and mounting a subtree of a filesystem as a different subdirectory within the same filesystem and volume (aka directory hardlink).

Comment: If `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Homework` is a reparse point where a different entire filesystem is mounted, then a file `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Homework\Assignment1.txt` is actually in the root directory of the filesystem mounted there.  If that filesystem also is assigned drive letter `D:`, then the file has two names, `C:\Users\Me\Documents\Homework\Assignment1.txt` and `D:\Assignment1.txt`

Comment: @Ben Voigt Oh okay thank you for clarifying filesystems and filesystem layouts. I'm confused about the different types of reparse points you mentioned. What are the differences between them? The first one you mentioned is when you go into Disk Management and create a mount folder? The second one is the same but you're mounting a subfolder of a drive e.g. D:\Games instead of the first one which was D:? I'm confused about the third one too.

Comment: Mounting a disk as a drive letter is an obsolete thing that just keeps hanging around decades after becoming obsolete.. The replacement way, which is barely used, is to mount a disk in a folder.

Comment: Must be exam week, lots of homework assignments :)

Comment: @MeesterMoo: Correct, the first is in disk management and create a mount folder.  The second one is setup by the `subst` command.  The third one by the `mklink` command with the `/J` option.

Comment: @user1644677: I think mounting (a filesystem, not a disk) in a folder is far older than drive letters (just not available on Windows until relatively recently, but for most OSes it's how all mounts work)  And in Windows, drive letters are hardly obsolete, since you have to start with a drive letter in order to reach a reparse point in the first place.

Comment: @user1644677 Just to clarify, are any of the two things you mentioned the same of the three things that Ben Voigt mentioned? Thank you for helping me

Comment: @BenVoigt Ahh. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MiG I'm studying for the Comptia A+ lol

Comment: @MeesterMoo: You should review https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/reparse-points since Reparse Points are the common foundation.   "Reparse points are also used to implement mounted folders."

Comment: @user1644677  -- What nonsense.  `Mounting a disk as a drive letter is an obsolete thing` and `keeps hanging around decades after becoming obsolete` make no sense in the same sentence.  What definition of "obsolete" are you using?  The drive letter, (howbeit sort of stupid) dates all of the way back to CPM and is still in use today.  Show me a windows machine (yes, 75% market share) without a C: drive or *average* people smart enough to use junctions or reparse points to mount volumes/partitions.  My mom plugs in a USB stick and up pops a new drive letter.  Stupid.. but hardly "obsolete".

Comment: But it was replaced by NTFS functions directed at servers so you can add disk space to a drive by using multiple drives. Also the root of a computer for users is the Desktop folder in which drives are in a sub folder called Computer that users don't access as the start programs from start and look for files in Documents.

Comment: @BenVoigt You are mistaking compatibility features to allow MSDos 1 programs (no sub folders) to run on MSDos 2 computers. `Join`, `subst`, and `append` (now called `DPath`  in Cmd.exe - type `dpath /?`).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas See I read all the press releases in the 90s and till mid 2000s. Note explorer has an option to hide drive letters. Obviously users objected to that so is off by default/

Comment: @user1644677 , I was there coding for Microsoft during those press release years starting with Windows for workgroups 3.11.. (and code for Microsoft now).  Lets agree to disagree.  :)  I am just saying "not obsolete" even though unix has always (imho) had a better method for mounting file systems.  Microsoft won the war (back then) by keeping compatibility with things like the drive letter.  Lots of CODE would work if you took it away.. some would.. some wouldn't as many apps don't work properly using UNC.

Comment: @user1644677: The purpose of those commands may be backward compatibility (not back to DOS 1 though) but the implementation uses the same file system filters and reparse points as the "Mounted Folder" feature.